# Ask user what application to open hyperlink with

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone know how I can prompt the user to choose between two applications when clicking on a specific type of Hyperlink(so as to open the relevant file)?
I guess it has something to do with application.open..

Answer (score 0):

If you know path to these two applications you could just do a shell command

```
Sub app1_Click()
    openInApplication("C:\Path\to\app1", hyperLink)
End Sub

Sub app2_Click()
    openInApplication("C:\Path\to\app2", hyperLink)
End Sub

Sub openInApplication(pathToApp as String, hyperLink as String)
    If Dir(pathToApp) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Path Not Found", vbCritical, "Macro Ending"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Shell """" & pathToApp & """" & hyperLink
End Sub
```